# Upload Image file using Symfony2 without guessers?

Tags: symfony, file-upload, components, symfony-2.1

I am using Symfony2 framework for one of my project. In this one, I want to upload an image. This is really easy to do so while following the Symfony2's cookbook. It works very well on my local machine. But when I put the whole application on my remote server (Planethoster.net shared hosting), it doesn't work because of the Type-Mime extension guessers. In fact, they are not enable on their servers... (phpinfo shows --disable-fileinfo)

So, basically the idea is to know if there is a solution to do the same action (uploading an image) without any extension guessers?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What do you think of filtering the filename ? With the last three characters, you'll know the extension. Check out [UploadedFile](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html), there is a getClientOriginalName() method. What I would do is to explode it by the `.`, fetch the second entry of the resulting array, and then parse it to do what you want to do.

Would you like an example of code ?

Comment: Thank you, the thing is that I want that the upload be aborted for any wrong mime-type. I.e. if the user rename the extension, I want my app to block the file upload. So far, I have done something similar to what you suggested me, but I am not 100% satisfied with that.

Comment: Hello, how do you do then to refuse the upload ? The first thing that came to my mind was an exception, but I'm not entirely sure they can be thrown from entities.

Comment: or getClientOriginalExtension()

Answer (score 1):

To fix exception while uploading file using framework Symfony 2

Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available.

enable PHP extension php_fileinfo, to do this find your php.ini file and uncomment following line

```
; windows
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

or

```
; linux
extension=php_fileinfo.so
```